# Map domain name to multiple AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-elb

The company I work for has multiple elastic beanstalk applications. We have setup a domain (eg. http://applications.ourcompany.com ) that currently directs to one of these instances. This works fine, the user enters http://applications.ourcompany.com and they end up at this ELB instance. However what we would really like to to is have something like the following:

http://applications.ourcompany.com/appone - maps to http://appone.elasticbeanstalk.com

http://applications.ourcompany.com/apptwo - maps to http://apptwo.elasticbeanstalk.com

and so on. I have been reading the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) but it isn't immediately obvious if this is possible, or how to go about it. This is further complicated by our need to use HTTPS for at least one of these instances. We currently have a certificate for http://applications.ourcompany.com in IAM. Any help or guidance hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this with a custom proxy server. The path ('/appone', '/apptwo') is passed to the application, not checked by the DNS. So you could set up an HAProxy server or nginx or something on http://applications.ourcompany.com and have it proxy requests to the different apps on https://appone.elastibeanstalk.com (notice I added HTTPS there).